# Python Crawler is unable to scrape the required element

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am trying to scrape few elements from a specific page: in this case "*http://www.mega.pk/mobiles/*" but the problem I am facing is that I am unable to scrape anything except for the product name and anything else just returns null. Please Help me out in correct direction and I would be thankful if you explain what's the issue is.

**NOTE:**  okay so I have changed the way I was scraping data before and now using scrapy. Now I am able to scrap any element I want but tags are also with it. How can I remove the tags?
Here's the new code:

```
sel = Selector(response)

item['Heading'] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="main1"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/h2/span').extract()
item['Content'] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="main1"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/p').extract()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `/text()` at the end of your xpath.

```
sel = Selector(response)

item['Heading'] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="main1"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/h2/span/text()').extract()
item['Content'] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="main1"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/p/text()').extract()
```